# Dealing with points vs. rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I fear I've missed some crucial point in my education thus far.

I have a table `HR` and I've performed functions on it.

For example `HR$FTE <- HR$'Std Hrs' / 38` gives me a new column for each employee; working as intended.

However, whenever I try to perform a function when creating a new column it doesn't like that. The question that I posted yesterday is similar in nature where the error result was from returning the whole row.

An example function that doesn't work would be `HR$FYEnd <- as.Date(paste(HR$FY + 1,"06","30", sep = "-"))`. In this case, `non-numeric argument to binary operator` is returned, as `HR$FY` is not numeric but rather a column of numeric data. What should be outputted is a set of dates on 30/06.

In Excel (which I'm trying to train myself to leave) the equivalent when dealing with tables would be `[@[FY Start]]` or something to that effect which demonstrates that you're working with the figure on that row rather than the whole row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out - couple of days later.

The step that I was missing was using the `mapply`/`sapply` commands. Using these has sorted everything out.